# Getting Java Lang Null pointer exception in Android

Tags: java, android

I've been coding an android app and i've suddenly started getting an error, the error log says there is  Java.Lang.Null.pointer.exception on line 23 of my Game.java yet none of the code concerning that has been changed. Here is the code: Any ideas?

Main class

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {        
    case R.id.about_button:
        Intent i = new Intent(this, About.class);
        startActivity(i);
        break;
    case R.id.ext_button:
        finish();
        break;

    case R.id.new_button:

        openNewGameDialog();
        break;
    }
}

private void openNewGameDialog() {

    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)

    .setTitle(R.string.diff_head)

    .setItems(R.array.difficulty,

     new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialoginterface, 
                int i) {

            startGame(i);

        }
    })

    .show();
}


private void startGame(int i) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Game.class);

    intent.putExtra(Game.KEY_DIFFICULTY, i);

    startActivity(intent); 
}
```

Game.java

```
public class Game extends Activity {

public static final String KEY_DIFFICULTY = "w1279057.CW1.difficulty";
public static final int DIFFICULTY_NOVICE = 0;
public static final int DIFFICULTY_EASY = 1;
public static final int DIFFICULTY_MEDIUM = 2;
public static final int DIFFICULTY_GURU = 3;




            Random rand = new Random();


line 23 >>  int diff = getIntent().getIntExtra(KEY_DIFFICULTY, DIFFICULTY_NOVICE);

@Override   
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

Comment: Can you post stacktrace too?.

Comment: `getIntent()` must be returning a null value, then when you call `getIntExtra(..)` on the null value you get your exception.

Comment: getIntent returns null because onCreate wasnt called first.... Move this line to onCreate edit:after super.onCreate

Comment: sorry i'm still fair new to programming, what is a stacktrace exactly?

Comment: On android you can find it in logcat log

Comment: Thanks Selvin you're suggestion worked! I must have moved it at somepoint without thinking.

Comment: @nexus490 It's okay. as Selvin said, you should move `diff` declaration into onCreate method, below `setContent` line. By the way, `stacktrace` shows details of error. In example; logcat view displays these error in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

If that's the line where it's happening, then that means that the value being returned from `getIntent()` is null. This is why you should always avoid calling methods on the return results of method calls (see [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)).

You should double check and see how this activity is getting started. Chances are the troubles are there.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't upload enough code to make it clear.. But if I had to guess.. 
getIntent() will only return a non-null value if its being called from the startGame() method. You will get a nullpointer if youre activity restarts (i.e. orientation change). try something like this.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState
    int diff;
    if(savedInstanceState == null)
         diff = getIntent().getIntExtra(KEY_DIFFICULTY, DIFFICULTY_NOVICE);
}
```

and then if you want to save the state look at the method onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle outstate)